# Get free SP500 historical end of day data through API

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance, quandl

Is there any way to get free SP500 historical end-of-day data ideally in API and csv form? Not sure why it seems to be harder than I could imagine.

For example:

Quandl: SPY or SPX symbol not found

```
rs = requests.get('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/SPY/data.csv?api_key=<API Keys>')
```

Is there any API that I could try?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve it via API by installing quandl with `pip install quandl` and then making a request as follows:

```
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'YOUR_KEY'
quandl.get('EOD/SPY', start_date='2021-02-26', end_date='2021-02-26')
```

However, you need to be subscribed to the dataset to be able to access the data this way.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I ended up using https://iexcloud.io/

Comment: The documentation is so much more clear than quandl in my opinion